# MATLAB : Learning by self

Tags: matlab

I have self skilled on MATLAB basics and its functionalities. However I found that project implementation in MATLAB is subject to theoretical information on same domain. Being from a non-engineering field I am finding it quiet difficult to implement short projects.

I tried to search for websites which has a few free MATLAB projects source code available or MATLAB projects source code hosted - I wished to pursue, read and parse the implementation, but could not find any. Website either hosted the zip file having empty / incomplete codes.

Please let me know if there is a genuine / good website where free MATLAB project source code is available? It would be best if it has something related to DSP, Image Processing and Numerical Analysis.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Peter Kovesi](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/) has a nice library, as does [Piotr Dollár](http://vision.ucsd.edu/~pdollar/toolbox/doc/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/

there are many many solved problems there.

look for the higher rated ones, and read through.

enjoy

Comment: Thanks for the link - wrt to reply from @EngrStudent I would definitely buy this book - is there any sites which has DSP / Image Processing source codes?

Answer (score 1):

I found the textbook by Maghrab to be very useful.
http://amzn.com/B008ITDEKI

It is not a website, but it was really quite good.

When you say 'projects' do you mean engineering-related tasks, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned that I am self learner and beginner - projects could be related to anything which would give me an insight to MATLAB functionalities, be it engineering-related tasks, medical or anything else

Comment: If you work through the textbook with its end-of-chapter problems then you will have worked through many useful projects by the end of the book.  If you are trying and you run into a roadblock - you can ask me for some help.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I would definitely buy this book - is there any sites which has DSP / Image Processing source codes?

Comment: Thre should be.  If I were MathWorks and I wanted to establish my embedded self, I would do something like Parllax did with the Basic Stamp Boot camp.

Comment: Try these: http://www.mathworks.com/products/embedded-coder/model-examples.html
They aren't DSP as much as embedded, but they will get you some mileage into putting your MatLab code on someone elses silicon.